# mySql queries doing nothing when done via axios

Tags: javascript, mysql, vue.js, axios

I have a *MySQL* server hooked up to a node API.

On the *Postman* I can make a `POST` request to `{{api_root}}/client/edit`

with this body:

```
{
    id: 1,
    field: deleted,
    value: 1
}
```

and the response is:

```
{
    "fieldCount": 0,
    "affectedRows": 1,
    "insertId": 0,
    "serverStatus": 2,
    "warningCount": 0,
    "message": "(Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0",
    "protocol41": true,
    "changedRows": 1
}
```

So I then implement this into the *Vue* client with *Axios*

```
async function edit( client, field, value ) {
  const url = api + '/client/edit'
  const bearer = getBearer()

  return await Axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    timeout: 30000,
    headers: { Authorization: bearer },
    data: {
      id: client,
      field: field,
      value: value
    }
  })
}
```

I can see on the network tab, it's going to the right place, its a `POST` and has the following payload

```
field: "deleted"
id: 1
value: 1
```

Keep in mind when I changed 'deleted' to a field that doesn't exist, it throws an error, so it's definitely going to the right place with the right params.

My response is

```
affectedRows: 1
changedRows: 0
fieldCount: 0
insertId: 0
message: "Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1"
protocol41: true
serverStatus: 2
warningCount: 1
```

And nothing in the database has changed, any help is appreciated

Comment: Well, there is a warning. You should check what it says!

Comment: it just seems to be an int, and i cant actually see the warning is

Comment: Use the `show warnings` mysql statement after the update to get the actual warning.